# Angular + firebase - can't get the key value in html

Tags: html, angular, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I want to navigate to an URL based on the key of an object in my database, but when i acces the p.$key value is always undefined.

service:

```
 getAll(){
    return this.db.list('/products').valueChanges();
  }
```

component:

```
 products$;

  constructor(private productService: ProductService) { 

    this.products$ = this.productService.getAll();
    
  }
```

html:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let p of products$ | async">
            <td>{{p.title}}</td>
            <td>{{p.price}}</td>
            <td>
                <a [routerLink]="['/admin/products/', p.$key]" >Edit</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]
I am getting the right values for p.title and p.price, but p.$key is always undefined. I also tried p.key , same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `valueChanges()` stream doesn't include the key of the nodes. According to the AngularFire documentation on [`valueChanges`](When would you not use it? - When you need a more complex data structure than an array or you need the key of each snapshot for data manipulation methods. This method assumes you either are saving the key for the snapshot data or using a "readonly" approach.):

> When would you not use it? - When you need a more complex data structure than an array or you need the key of each snapshot for data manipulation methods. This method assumes you either are saving the key for the snapshot data or using a "readonly" approach.

I think you may want to use the [`snapshotChanges` stream](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md#snapshotchanges) instead, which gives you the entire `DataSnapshot` for each object from which you can get the `key` and the `val()`.

Comment: Can you please give me a little bit more information on how should i use stateChanges in this particular situation? i tried using it with and without subscribing but it's not working either way. I just started working with firebase so i'm a little bit newby.

Comment: Sorry, I had overlooked the `snapshotChanges` stream yesterday, which is probably the one you want to use. I update my answer and provided a link to the relevant documentation.

Comment: i did that, indeed now my key is working but the problem is the title and price are not working anymore. I am assuming that this is happening because i need to acces that node's child to get the data, but i'm not sure how to do that. I updated my post with a ss from my firebase database.

Comment: nvm,i figured it out. i need to do it this way: p.payload.val().title .  Thanks very much !

Comment: Good to hear you got it working. And sorry about the red herring on `stateChanges`. I accentially overlooked the `snapshotChanges()` stream in the docs at first.

Answer (score 1):

**Service:**

Pipe is not necessary. I used it so you can console.log your object to view.

```
  getAll(){
    return this.db.list('/products').snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
      map(object => {
        console.log(object);
        return object;
      })
    );
  }
```

**Component**

Same as yours

**html**

```
<span *ngFor="let item of items$ | async">
    <!-- print out the key values -->
    {{item.key}}
</span>
```